# Sending data to my master page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm working on an intranet (correcting bugs and adding features) - but there's an issue with the display of the administrator tab, it display either way !

I am now able to know if the Employee is an administrator or not with the following SQL request :

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    // Variables
    string isAdministrator;
    bool isAdmin;

    // Checks the admin status of logging in user
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT isAdministrator FROM Employee WHERE Login = '" + model.UserName + "'", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    isAdministrator = reader[0].ToString();
                    isAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(isAdministrator);
                    ViewData["isAdmin"] = isAdmin;
                }   
            }            
         }
     }            


      // Not relevant things related to logging in
  return View(model);
}
```

The behavior should be : if `isAdmin` is true, display Administration tab (or simply deny its access) if not, don't.

But I have two major issues :

- I wonder where I can fill my `isAdmin` variable to have it filled no matter what (so that I don't have to log in to have it filled)
- And I don't know how to pass it's value to my `Site.Master`

Comment: Use SqlParameter to prevent sql injection.

Comment: I am going to take care of the security issue as soon as possible, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example `ViewBag.IsAdmin = 1` like:

```
...
while (reader.Read())
{
    isAdministrator = reader[0].ToString();
    isAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(isAdministrator);
    ViewBag.IsAdmin = isAdmin;
    break;
}   
...
```

and then in the _Layout.cshtml you can use variable from ViewBag like:

```
@if(ViewBag.IsAdmin == 1)
{
    <div>
    </div>
}
```

But In my opinion you should look for the `SimpleMembership` functionality.

Then you can use:

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    <div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Isn't ViewBag used to send data to a View and not a Master page? I wish to send it to the Master page so that I can deny access or stop displaying the admin page if needed.

Comment: Turns out I created roles and everything that goes with it for the SimpleMembership, it works like a charm.